# Joint distribution of uniform variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

$$X_{1}\sim \mathcal{Uniform}([0,2])$$
$$X_{2}\sim \mathcal{Uniform}([1,2])$$

$X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are *independent* random variables.

My question is whether joint distribution of those variables is:
$$f(x_{1},x_{2})=f_{1}(x_{1})\,f_2(x_{2})=1/2$$

... for all $(x_1, x_2) \in\ [0,2]{\times}[1,2]$?

If answer is incorrect, then how to approach this issue?

If answer is correct, then I am thinking wheter exist more rigorous and formal approach to derive this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer: Yes, you are correct.**

But you asked for rigor... I'll try to make the rationale rigorous for your edification :P Hopefully I don't end up confusing you, but rather send you on an adventure to learn more formal probability theory.

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$ be our underlying [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) (meaning all random variables we discuss here are assumed to be [$\mathscr{F}$-measurable functions of $\omega \in \Omega$](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-436j-fundamentals-of-probability-fall-2008/lecture-notes/MIT6_436JF08_lec05.pdf)).

Consider the following random variable $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^2$,
$$X = \begin{bmatrix}X_1 \\ X_2\end{bmatrix}$$

Notice that the components of $X$ are also random variables, $X_1: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and $X_2: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.

Let the [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) (PDF) of $X$ be called $f(x) = f(x_1,x_2)$, and let the PDFs of its components $X_1$ and $X_2$ be called $f_1(x_1)$ and $f_2(x_2)$ respectively. We define a conditional PDF as,
$$f_1(x_1 | x_2) := \frac{f(x_1, x_2)}{f_2(x_2)}$$
When we say "$X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent" we strictly mean,
$$f_1(x_1 | x_2) \equiv f_1(x_1)$$

So like you said,
$$f(x_1, x_2) = f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2)$$

If $f_1(x_1)$ is uniform on $[0,2]$ then,
$$f_1(x_1)
:= \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}, & x_1 \in [0,2] \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$
and similarly, $f_2(x_2)$ uniform on $[1,2]$ means,
$$f_2(x_2)
:= \begin{cases}
1, & x_2 \in [1,2] \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

So we must have,
$$f(x_1,x_2) = f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2)
= \begin{cases}
(\frac{1}{2})(1), & x_1 \in [0,2]\ \cap\  x_2 \in [1,2] \\
(\frac{1}{2})(0), & x_1 \in [0,2]\ \cap\  x_2 \not\in [1,2] \\
(0)(1), & x_1 \not\in [0,2]\ \cap\  x_2 \in [1,2] \\
(0)(0), & x_1 \not\in [0,2]\ \cap\  x_2 \not\in [1,2] \\
\end{cases}$$

which can be expressed more simply as,
$$f(x_1,x_2)
= \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}, & x_1, x_2 \in [0,2]\times[1,2] \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

It is good to verify that your result is indeed a valid PDF,
$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x)dx = \int_1^2 \int_0^2\frac{1}{2}dx_1dx_2 = 1$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56698/discussion-on-answer-by-jnez71-joint-distribution-of-uniform-variables).